# Sync FTP and local folder - Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, directory, synchronization

I've shared hosting with no SSH access. Just simple FTP access.

I've a team of 5 developers working on multiple projects. For any modification on project files, I manually upload all files using filezilla which is getting difficult day by day (because of human errors and time constraints).

I'm not sure if there is a way where I can map a specific local folder with the webfolder using FTP.

For ex. I'll change test.php on local server and run a terminal account - "sync" then it should automatically detect that test.php is updated and should replace server's test.php with the latest one.

Another example - if I edit a specific file in FTP, then it should sync with the local folder.

Another constraint is I cannot give my FTP password to my team because of compliance issues, no need that restricted.

Please assist if there is a way to do this OR anything better.

Appreciate your help. You're awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to mount an FTP folder.

The package [curlftpfs](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/curlftpfs) (available in Ubuntu `universe` repository) enables you to do that.

Comment: You cannot hide totally the password of a ftp client; it is at least in the conf. Unless you use a private key, which is, as far as I know, not supported by the FTP protocol. If you want to use keys, use the sFTP protocol (FTP over SSH).